# vue-tippy with a single global popup for multiple buttons

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tippyjs

I'm using vue-tippy 6.0.0-alpha.63 for vue3.
I have a single component on the page which has a dynamic content and want to make a tooltip from it. This tooltip should be shown when user moves mouse over one of many buttons with class `skill_tab`. Those buttons are nested deeply inside the parent component of the current component.

I wrapped the component content with a `<tippy>` component and I'm trying to bind the tooltip to the buttons using `to` prop but it doesn't work.
I also tried using the `triggerTarget` prop providing the class `.skill_tab` as the value, but it looks like `triggerTarget` only works with refs.

Component for a button:

*SkillTab.Vue*

```
<div class="skill_tab">
    ...
</div>
```

Component for the tooltip:

*SkillTooltip.Vue*

```
<tippy followCursor=true to=".skill_tab" allowHtml=true placement="bottom-end" interactive=true>
    <div id="skill_tooltip" class="skill_tooltip" :class="{active}" v-if="active">
        ...
    </div>
</tippy>
```

Is there any way to bind the tooltip to all the buttons without passing refs via a global state or any other simple way?

Comment: Maybe you could set the trigger to manual and then use the capture event modifier to get the mouseover event from your child buttons onto your tippy element and trigger the tooltip manually?

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Comment: I'm not sure how it should work. Could you post an answer? I ended up using the composable API and binding on document.body instead of buttons. You can check on the live site. https://twwh-chars.com/en/characters/chs_archaon

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you were trying to do. Is it possible to share a bit of your code so I can understand better and try to have a go at it, or else if you happy since it's already working, then I guess we're good.

Comment: @aghashamim What kind of code do you need? I added the relevant markup for the buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. That's all I needed. I guess this is what you were trying to achieve?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-ttbgcc?file=src/components/Buttons.vue

I am not quite familiar with Vue3 and the composition api, so you'll just have to set the tippy content to your relevant component by creating an instance of it and it should work, of course unless I didn't really understand your problem correctly.

Comment: @aghashamim I cannot do this, because the buttons are all over the page, in different nesting contexts. They cannot be put into one wrapper.